# How to do Pub/Sub on WSO2 Message Broker with WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wso2

There seems to be very little information on interacting with the WSO2 products from WCF or .Net in general. I am attempting to subscribe to a Topic which is defined in the WSO2 Message Broker, but I have no idea where to start. Eventually, I'd like to publish events from a C# application, but again, I could use some help finding a starting point.

I've successfully coded something up using the RabbitMQ .net libraries, but only for reading/writing to a queue, not a topic. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Cant tell if serious
or trolling.

Comment: Serious, not sure what that is.

Comment: Its an open source Service Oriented Architecture framework with stuff like Service Bus and Message Brokering, etc. [link](http://wso2.org)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this using WS-Eventing API by writing a C# client. You can refer the section on WS-Eventing in [this](http://wso2.org/library/articles/2011/08/messaging-eventing-soa#eventing) article. Unfortunately, the example code is in Java.

Comment: thanks @keheliya. I had seen that article, but their sample seems to use some custom WSO2 java libraries (BrokerClient et al.) This seems to be where all the heavy lifting is, so without those libraries it seems like a lot of work.